# PHP, cURL request not fetching data

Tags: php

I want to get some informations through github API, i tried to use file_get_contents and it does not seem to work, so i moved to cURL, it does not give an error but it's not returning anything

PHP code :

```
if (!empty($_POST["username"])) {
        $ch=curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.github.com/users/".$_POST["username"]);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        $output=curl_exec($ch);
        print_r($output);
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

I checked the http code with CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE and its set to 0. is there any fix that i can get the json data when requesting.

Comment: Try to print out an error, if there is any: `echo curl_error ($ch);` before closing. See what comes up.

Comment: Are you authenticated/permitted to make that request? If you run that request with a valid username you should get: "_Request forbidden by administrative rules. Please make sure your request has a User-Agent header (http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required). Check https://developer.github.com for other possible causes._"

Comment: @kerbholz yes i already read, these informations does not any authentication, i tried few requests on different accounts with postman and its working fine.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy my bad, am getting curl_error(Resource id #4)

Comment: Postman might send a User-Agent with the request, your script doesn't. Also make sure `$_POST["username"]` is a valid user and doesn't contain any whitespace. (Just tested with a UserAgent set without problems)

Comment: @kerbholz even if i set the url myself without any variables am having the same issue, executing the url on browser gives me a json data

Comment: That's probably because if you send the request via your browser, a `User-Agent` header will be added to the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried accessing the same URL using curl in php and it seems to work fine. Checkout the following example:

```php
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<?php
if (!empty($_POST["username"])) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.github.com/users/".$_POST["username"]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($output);
}
?>
```

Comment: @hosien in jast, you added mozilla agent ?, where to find this please ?

Comment: From https://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required: "_We request that you use your GitHub username, or the name of your application, for the User-Agent header value. This allows us to contact you if there are problems._"

Comment: github say that but work nice with mozila. you can add your username or app name

Comment: huh, i just downloaded mozilla to give it a try, and it still not working, jeez am giving up :(, and i did use my name for the user header agent and its not working

Comment: You didn't need Firefox.but its work fine for me
```
https://ibb.co/zPCnjVQ
```
on wrong username
```
{ "message": "Not Found", "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user" }
```

Comment: I just can't understand why it's not working here, it's the same code, 
<form method="post">
                <input type="text" name="username"><br><br>
                <button type="submit" name="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
and this the html code, i just can't get it, what is the user-agent, used the mozilla one and my name, and still,

Comment: jeez, copy paste it the exact same code, and it's not working :') 
the html + php, when ever i enter a user it just refreshs and am not getting anything, with both opera, and mozilla

Comment: Make sure curl enabled.and firewall was open if user dident exist github return an array of error like my prev comment

Answer (score 0):

Running that script as is will return an error message about User-Agent:

> Request forbidden by administrative rules. Please make sure your request has a User-Agent header (http://developer.github.com/v3/#user-agent-required). Check https://developer.github.com for other possible causes.

From that site: "*All API requests MUST include a valid User-Agent header. Requests with no User-Agent header will be rejected.*"

So, to add a User-Agent header to your cURL-request change your code to

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST["username"])) {
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.github.com/users/".$_POST["username"]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Oussama Mater Test-App'); // line added
    $output=curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($output);
    curl_close($ch);
} else {
    echo "No POST username";
}
```

Complete code with form:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>

<?php

if (!empty($_POST["username"])) {
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.github.com/users/" . $_POST["username"]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Oussama Mater Test-App');
    $output=curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($output);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: i truly did not know where to find this error message about User-Agent, i changed the code and still did not get any output, im sorry this is my first time with APIs

Comment: Sorry, had the wrong (testing) code posted, fixed my answer. Are you sure that `if` is triggered/`$_POST["username"]` is actually set? Can you add an `else { echo "no post";}` just to make sure?

Comment: yes it is triggered, just added the else, if the $_POST["username"] empty it will echo no post.

Comment: Hm, then I am at a loss, sorry, that code works perfectly fine on my end here. Sorry I can't be of any more help, will remove my answer in < 5 mins

Comment: the code that works perfect, is the one you posted ?

Comment: I added my "complete code with form", yes, that one is working without problems, can fetch JSON info about different users on github (Linux Mint, using `php -S 127.0.0.1:8000` to serve pages)

Comment: i would be glad if you send me the code, i'll compare by own and make conclusions and it did not work for me. been working for this small app 4hrs56mins exactly and i truly wanna know why it's not working.

Comment: The code is already there in my answer, the "Complete code with form" section, there's nothing more to it. Good luck

Comment: thank you very much for taking time to answer, i appreciate it.